# Problem when logging in using AnsycTask on android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I am using MySQL as a bank hosted on an AWS server

I use the AsyncTask class to login, doing the search with SELECT * from ... I check the search with ResultSet, the code executes quietly, but when I click the Login button, it goes into exception.

I use the same code to insert data into the database and it performs right

Only verification is not right

```
public class Tela_Login extends AppCompatActivity {
ConnectionClass connectionClass;
EditText editUsuario, editSenha;
Button btLogin;
TextView textCadastro;
ProgressBar pbbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela__login);
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;

    editUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsuario);
    editSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
    textCadastro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCadastro);
    btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
    pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            realizarLogin realizarLogin = new realizarLogin();
            btLogin.setClickable(false);
            realizarLogin.execute("");

        }
    });
}
public class realizarLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;




    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(Tela_Login.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(Tela_Login.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String usuario = editUsuario.getText().toString();
        String senha = editSenha.getText().toString();

        if (usuario.trim().equals("") || senha.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Por favor os valores!";
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Erro ao conectar no banco de dados";
                } else {
                    String query = "select * from Salao where email='" +usuario+"' and senha='" +senha+"'";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs;
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        z = "Login sucessful";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    } else {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "Exceptions";
            }
        }
        btLogin.setClickable(true);
        return z;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: *it goes into exception* - there is a remote possibility that posting that exception here might help us (or you) finding the issue

Comment: where do I see what exception it gave in android studio?

Comment: It appeared in the run : W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection